# some confusions about the concepts of algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Recently I tried to learn Algebra(Revised third edition) with the book written by Serge Lang. Since I have not covered all topics in the elegant book but now just view it as a reference for some important concepts, so I encounter some confusions when reading.

Chapter XIV Representation of one endmorphism

1. page 556 here define the notion minimal polynomial of A over k, where k is a field and A is a endomorphism of finite dimension vector space E over k. it is unique thus well-defined. However, at next page 557,  "If E=(v) is principal...the minimal polynomial is uniquely determined by A, and does not depend on the choice of generator v for E" 
   I feel confused that even in the definition it is already uniquely defined, why Lang would say not depend on...?
2. page 561 when we define characteristic polynomial P M(t)=det(tI n - M), where M be any n x n matrix in k. If we use the notations as before, t should be transcendental over k.
   I feel confused that why we have to restrict to transcendental elements in k, how about if a field has no one is transcendental?

THX!

Comment: $t$ is an indeterminate here.

Comment: @MorganRodgers thank you so much, I have just read some books about linear algebra since I'm not major in mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the definition p 556, the minimal polynomial is only said to be unique once the vector space $E$ has been fixed. So in general it can depend on that $E.$

Then he says if the vector space $E$ over $A$ happens to be generated by some single $v,$ then it follows that changing the generator $v$ of that $E$ does not change the minimal polynomial. This is in fact not immediate from his above definition, since changing the generator of $E$ is in a way changing $E$ itself. [Note it may be "obvious", I'm just saying it's not an immediate consequence without knowledge of vector spaces and what Lang means by saying $E=(v)$ is principal.]